# How to insert large amounts of CSV data to MySQL database using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv

I have a huge CSV file with ~1 million records. I want to insert them to my MySQL database.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
// sync method to insert csv to mysql db
// csv -> js array -> sql query

const parseCSV = require('csv-parse/lib/sync')
const csvdata = fs.readFileSync("myfile.csv");



// convert csv to js array
let records = parseCSV(csvdata, {
    columns: true,
    skip_empty_lines: true
});



// convert js array to one big SQL query
let query = `INSERT INTO my_table VALUES `;

for (let record of records) {

    const fields = [
        'field1', 'field2', 'field3'
    ];

    let subQuery = "";

    fields.forEach(field => {
        if (record[field]) {
            subQuery += `"${record[field]}",`;
        } else {
            subQuery += "NULL" + ",";
        }
    })

    // remove the comma from the end of sub query
    subQuery = subQuery.slice(0, -1)

    // append it to the main query
    query += `(${subQuery}),`
}

// remove comma from the end of main query
query = query.slice(0, -1);

let [result] = await dbConn.promise().execute(query);
res.send({ error: false, message: `${result.affectedRows} new records have been created.` });
```

The problem I am facing is that when I convert csv to a js array, heap overflow occurs. Even if I am able to make the query, sending such a big query to the db can be a problem.

I have also tried using fs.createReadStream in the following manner.

```js
// insert csv to mysql db using stream
// csv -> sql query
const csvParser = require('csv-parser');

const fields = [
    'field1', 'field2', 'field3'
];


// convert each record of csv and make separate SQL query for each record
fs.createReadStream("myfile.csv")
    .pipe(csvParser())
    .on('data', async (record) => {

        let query = `INSERT INTO primary_table VALUES `;
        let subQuery = "";

        fields.forEach(field => {
            if (record[field]) {
                subQuery += `"` + record[field] + `"` + ",";
            } else {
                subQuery += "NULL" + ",";
            }
        })

        // remove the comma from the end of sub query            
        subQuery = subQuery.slice(0, -1)

        // make the complete query
        query += `(${subQuery}),`

        // remove comma from the end of main query
        query = query.slice(0, -1);

        try {
            let [result] = await dbConn.promise().execute(query);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("SQL ERROR");
        }
    })
    .on('error', (err) => { console.log(`Error \n\n`, err); })
    .on('end', async () => {
        console.log('Data sent to DB')
        return res.send({ error: false, message: `New records have been created.` });
    });
```

Here the issue is that the server will send 1 million queries to the DB which is again very slow.

Comment: Upload your CSV to MySQL then load it using LOAD DATA INFILE query. You don't need to load/parse it on the client side.

Comment: What you're doing here is extremely risky due to not properly escaping values. Always use placeholder values in your queries whenever possible. The safest thing is `LOAD DATA INFILE`.